# Insert dummy row in SQL select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am working on SQL Server stored procedure. I have a table 'User' having fields (Id, Name, Email,Address).

I have following query returning All Users

```
select * from [User]
```

It returns all users, but I just want to insert following dummy user to resulting record before returning it.

User => Id = 0, Name = "All"

This record will not be present with in the database but while returning result I want to insert this record as first record and then remaining users. I tried to find something like this but in vain.

Comment: Do a UNION ALL with "SELECT 0, 'ALL' FROM onerowtable".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT 0 AS Id, 'All' AS Name
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, Name FROM Users;
```

Comment: Thanks rob. Worked great.

Answer (score 0):

You can even set a column numerically to keep the order even though `UNION ALL` is applied

```
SELECT 0 RNO, 0 AS Id, 'All' AS Name
UNION ALL
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY  Id)RNO, Id, Name 
FROM Users
```

This will work even though a `Zero` exists in your column `Id`(may be a junk value)

Comment: Thanks. The syntax was quite complex for newbie like me.

Comment: Ohk. You can use whenever you need to be. Best wishes :) @Bilal Ahmed